# Is there a way to highlight find results in the scrollbar in Adobe Reader?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, adobe-reader

One of the features I really like in Chrome is that find results show up as little yellow highlights on the scrollbar (see below). [image]

Chrome's PDF reader is fine, but I prefer Adobe Reader. **Is there any similar highlighting feature available in Adobe Reader?**

When I'm searching a document by topic, sometimes a word might appear once or twice on one page, but on another page, it might appear 6 or 10 times. I'm often looking for the latter, as that's usually where the topic is actually discussed in detail. Chrome's feature gives me a quick visual reference to be able to find locations where my search term is heavily concentrated.